# How can I use invoke-sqlcmd without enabling named pipes?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using a script that loads the following SQL Server 2008 R2 powershell plugins

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

I then user invoke-sql like this:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from table" -ServerInstance xyz -Database abc -username xxxxxx -password yyyyyyy
```

I am using method to run a number of upgrade scripts on our databases. I was quite happily using this in our dev\test environments but then we I tried it in production and it turns out we have a difference in server configurations. On our prod servers named pipes are disabled for security reasons (apparently worm attacks) and our DBA's don't want to enable.

This is the error I get and research says it is a named pipes problem - starts working when I enable them too.

> INFO     ERROR: Invoke-Sqlcmd : A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
>   login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No
>   process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Does anyone know if there is some way to switch my script so that it does not require named pipes? Or is this the built in connection method for invoke-sqlcmd and I need to change tack (if so any suggestions).

Comment: If you figure it out concretely, please update.  I'm curious as well.

Comment: `invoke-sqlcmd -Query "select foo from bar" -HostName dbserver -Database fakedb`
resulted in
invoke-sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not 
accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 
40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But for some reason this works:
`invoke-sqlcmd -Query "select foo from bar" -serverinstance dbserver -Database fakedb`

Comment: `-HostName` is the wrong parameter. It's not the SQL Server name

Answer (score 2):

You can change the connection method using prefixes to the instance name [as for sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188247.aspx). With SQL Server 2012 and Powershell 4, this works for me:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlQuery -serverinstance "lpc:localhost" -Database "myDatabase"
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Surreal's response to use LPC (local shared memory), for TCP/IP instead of named pipes you can also specify `-ServerInstance tcp:foodb`

Answer (score 1):

This is an educated guess.  But here goes:

I think you have to "override the default" by using the registry.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229929

Now, the easiest way to do this (IIRC) is to go through your

```
Control Panel / ODBC Data Source / System DSN.
```

Add a "Sql Server".  (Not the native client ones).

The most important button is the "Client Configuration" where you can pick named-pipes or tcp/ip.
Try out the DSN method, and after completing the wizard, look at the registry entries under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
```

.........

You might check out this:

http://sev17.com/2012/11/05/cloning-sql-servers-to-a-test-environment/

Look for this code.

```
sqlcmd -S myCMServerInstance -d msdb -Q $query -h -1 -W |
foreach { Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWAREMicrosoftMSSQLServerClientConnectTo' -Name $($_ -replace 'TEST') -Value "DBMSSOCN,$_" }

}
```

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you may need an entry in the registry for "brvswidb1062" that is linked to dbmssoccn to override the default named pipes.  The DSN exercise shows how that works..via a GUI tool instead of trying to manually add the entries.